# python class methods returned globally?

Tags: python, inheritance, global

I have the following question:
I want to have the methods of a class available globally with out an instantiated object locally.

ex. file: a.py

```
class A(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        return

    def sp_a(self):
        print "a"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    return A()
```

file: test_a.py

```
import A

def run():
    sp_a()
```

Thanks

Comment: Why? You're better off just having a module with the functions declared there and calling `A.sp_a()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a method that needs to be global, why make it part of a class at all?

a.py

```
def sp_a():
    print "a"
```

test_a.py

```
from a import sp_a

def run():
    sp_a()
```

Comment: The requirements say create a factory for Class A.  So I am not really sure if I am on the right path or not.

Comment: A factory method would produce new instances of A. For instance, this is a factory method for instances of A: `def make_a(): a = A(); a.foo = 'a'; return a`. I think you may have misunderstood your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If it is stateless then you can make it a static method by decorating it with @staticmethod

```
class A(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        return

    @staticmethod
    def sp_a():
        print "a"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    return A()
```

file: test_a.py

```
import A

def run():
    A.sp_a()
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, which suggest using `staticmethod` you can also do this:

```
class A(object):
  @staticmethod
  def foo():
    # code

foo = A.foo
```

From that point, `foo` is a standalone name that you can import directly from the module, without having to import `A`.